# How to generate an array with repeated string javascript

Tags: javascript

How to generate an array with function like this?

```
var name = ["monkey","monkey"..."horse","horse",..."dog","dog",..."cat","cat"...]​
```

In my real case, I may have to repeat each name 100 times..

Comment: You want to generate that based on array where every word occurs once?

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){ name.push('cat'); }`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you already have that words in a array try this code:

```
var words = ["monkey", "hourse", "dog", "cat"];
var repeatWords = [];
for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < 100; j++)
  {
    repeatWords.push(words[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, specifying the words to be used, and the times to create the array you need.

```
var neededWords = ["Cat", "Hourse", "Dog"];
    var finalArray = [];
    var times = 10;
    for (var i = 0; i < neededWords.length; i++) {
        for (var n = 0; n < times; n++) {
            finalArray.push(neededWords[i]);
            }
    }
    console.log(finalArray);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you need a function that takes as an argument a collection of items and returns a collection of those items repeated. From your problem statement, I assumed that the repetition has to be adjusted by you per collection item - correct me if I am wrong.

The function I wrote does just that; it takes an object literal `{name1:frequency1,name2:frequency2..}` which then iterates over the keys and pushes each one as many times as indicated by the associated frequency in the frequencyMap object.

```
function getRepeatedNames( frequencyMap ) {
  var namesCollection = [];
  Object.keys(frequencyMap).forEach(function(name,i,names){
    var freq = frequencyMap[name];
    freq = (isFinite(freq)) ? Math.abs(Math.floor(freq)) : 1;
    for (var nameCounter=0; nameCounter<freq; nameCounter++) {
      namesCollection.push(name); 
    }
  });
  return namesCollection;
}
```

Non-numeric values in the frequency map are ignored and replaced with 1.

Usage example: If we want to create an array with 5 cats and 3 dogs we need to invoke

```
getRepeatedNames({cat: 2, dog: 3}); // ["cat","cat","dog","dog","dog"]
```